# How can I export public keys in PEM format with GnuPG?

Tags: gnupg, public-key

I know that `gpg --export -o pub.key -a "Username"` exports a users' public key, but it doesn't seem to write a standard PEM format block.

Is there any way to export keys from gpg in PEM format?

Answer (score 4):

You need the gpgsm utility, but, yes, you can.

```
gpgsm -o secret-key.p12 --export-secret-key-p12 0xXXXXXXXX
```

It contains keys and certificates. Then you can split them with openSSL and transform it in .pem at the same time

```
openssl pkcs12 -in secret-key.p12 -nocerts -out gpg-key.pem
openssl pkcs12 -in secret-key.p12 -nokeys -out gpg-certs.pem
```

Answer (score 4):

You need `gpgsm`.

To clone the keys from the `gpg` keystore to the `gpgsm` keystore, check [this comment](http://sysmic.org/dotclear/index.php?post/2010/03/24/Convert-keys-betweens-GnuPG%2C-OpenSsh-and-OpenSSL#c21688). Copying the solution here

```
 $ gpg --list-secret-keys --with-keygrip
 $ gpgsm --gen-key -o temporary.cert
 > Existing Key
 > use keygrip from gpg output
 > fill the X509 values
 > create a self signed certificate
 $ gpgsm --import temporary.cert
 $ gpgsm --list-keys
 > find the key just imported
 $ gpgsm -o cert.p12 --export-secret-key-p12 ${KEY_ID}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I just got "gpgsm: signing failed: Invalid ID" over and over again

Answer (score 1):

Use the `--export-ssh-key` option and then convert it to PEM:

```
ssh-keygen -f <(gpg --export-ssh-key <short_key_id>) -e -m pem
```

Comment: `-m pem` only works for RSA and produces the 'bare' PKCS1 format used only by some things (not most) built on OpenSSL/LibreSSL. The misleadingly-named `-m pkcs8` produces the much more common X.509 SPKI format standardized in RFC7468 and usable for RSA DSA ECDSA; the OpenSSH versions I have don't support Ed25519, although the format could/should. Also you must use `!` after the keyid if the (sub)key doesn't have usage `A` (authentication).

Answer (score 0):

Since GitLab needs the Public GPG key in PEM format, you could follow their [tutorial](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/gpg_signed_commits/#generating-a-gpg-key).

To export the private key to txt specifically:

```
gpg --armor --export-secret-keys 0x<key-ID>
```

or

```
gpg --armor --export-secret-keys "email-address"
```

Use the Key-ID or the email-address that was used to generate the private/secret key.

To write private key to disk:

```
gpg --armor --export-secret-keys "test@mail.com" > test.pem
```

To public key to txt/pem:

```
gpg --export -a "test@mail.com"
```

Remember to **use your email/key-id instead**.

Comment: `--armor` is the same as `-a` which the Question already had 8 years ago, and correctly states does NOT produce PEM. It produces PGP armor format, which is similar to PEM but is NOT PEM.