# Export lots gpg keys to pem format

Tags: gnupg, export

I have a lot of public keys (several hundreds all in one gpg file) and i would like to export each one to a separate pem file.

I've found many examples in internet where you need to explicitly type the ID of the key to export, but none that lets you export a bunch of keys.

Any way to do it?

Comment: You cannot export OpenPGP keys to the PEM format, at least not in a usable form in which they equiv the OpenPGP key. PEM is for X.509 keys, a completely different protocol from OpenPGP. Anyway: if you've got a solution for a _single_ key, it should be easy to put a simple script around that. Relevant information for the question would include how you converted a single key, and what operating system you're using.

Comment: @JensErat I'm using Debian 8 jessie as OS and all solutions i've found for single key are similar to the answer to [link](http://superuser.com/questions/435321/how-can-i-export-public-keys-in-pem-format-with-gnupg?rq=1) but the problem is i would rather not have to extract all key "ID's" and then iterate over them. I was wondering if there is a more direct way to do it